# Undefined service in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I have a service and a controller declared like this:

```
angular

.module('purchaseApp')

.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var stringValue = 'test string value';

    return {
        getString: function() {
            return stringValue;
        }
    }
})

.controller('purchaseOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, sharedProperties) {
   console.log(sharedProperties.getString());
});
```

When I try to access to the service in my controller, it returns me "undefined", but I don't know why... Could you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is missing `sharedProperties`. You need to inject it. Add it after `$http`.

```
.controller('purchaseOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location',  '$http', 'sharedProperties', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, sharedProperties) {
    console.log(sharedProperties.getString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('purchaseOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', **'sharedProperties'**, function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, sharedProperties) {
       console.log(sharedProperties.getString());
    });
```

Add sharedProperties service in your `controller` dependent parameter as well.